# JavaFX - How to refresh broken UI? After setItems() null value into table view

Tags: java, javafx

When I setItems() to my table view, put null value into by mistake. Then changed menu (load Other Controller on UI), UI was broken.

Almost control was gone, and some controls are mixed up. So to solve this problem I have to rerun my program.

```
FindResult<ImageInfo> result = this.imagService.find(query);   //result's all element is nulll
this.tableView.getItems().setAll(result.getList());
```

Before setItems,

[image]

When setItems null value,

[image]

I found one sloution. That is null check before setItems to table view. But It was a nuisance. **Because the code(null check) is so much located in my project code!**

What I want to do seems pretty two aspect,

1. Processing null value after setItems to table view
2. Refreshing broken JavaFX UI

know anyone?

Comment: You can post your code (edit the question) so that someone can take a look at  it and tell what is happening.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.